# Windows batch powershell command inside FOR loop not working

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, batch-file

I have the following for loop inside batch file:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %k%) do (

    set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password2' -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p

)
```

And I always get the following error:
**[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)"" was unexpected at this time.**

When I run the command outside the for loop, it works.

What is wrong?

Comment: Why on earth would you mix a batch with a PowerShell and not just use a PowerShell script directly? For one your quotes are off. You have a pair for `set` and one for the `-Command` and they're probably canceling each other.

Comment: it works outside the for loop so I assume that quotes are not the issue here

Comment: How do you run the command outside the for loop? What about placing the command between single quotes and Enter Password2 between double quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the for loop thinks that the end bracket is inside the powershell command.

The possible solution is to create a function and call it from the loop:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %k%) do (
    call :getPassword password
)

:getPassword
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: +1, Not how I would solve the issue, but you have properly diagnosed the source of the reported error.